# which is the fastest way to print in awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, printf, ksh

I am trying to make some measurements, and i would like to know what is the fastest way to print something through `nawk`.
at the moment i use `printf ARR[2] " ";`, but it seems to take more time than normal to print.

Info: I am printing around 500 numbers and adding the space in the `printf` so that not everything would be stucked together in the print out. Also i am running the script on ksh, in unix oracle solaris.

Like this, it needs around 14 seconds to print everything, is there any faster way i could do this?

Thanks in Advance!

***UPDATE***

The function that i care about is awkfun, in whuch i use `time` when i call it in order to make my time measurements.
Think of `NUMBERS` as a variable that holds 1000 random numbers, and `XNUMBERS` a variable that holds 1000 random number but in this format, `123|321`, so it takes the random number reverces it and adds a `|` in the middle.
I am checking for each of `NUMBERS` if it exhists in `XNUMBERS` and if it exhists i am printing out only the reversed number.

```
numfun() {
    NUMBERS=`nawk ' BEGIN{ 
        srand();
        for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", 100 + int(rand() * (899)));
        }   
    }'`
}
numfun
sleep 1
xnumfun() {
    XNUMBERS=`nawk ' BEGIN{ 
        srand();
        for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
            XNUMBERS[i]= 100 + int(rand() * (899));
        }
        for (i=0; i<=999; i++) {
            ver=XNUMBERS[i] "";
                    rev = "";
            for (q=length(ver); q!=0; q--) {
                rev = rev substr(ver, q, 1);
            }
            printf("%s\n", XNUMBERS[i] "|" rev );
        }
    }'`
}
xnumfun
awkfun() {
    for n in $NUMBERS
    do
        echo "${XNUMBERS}" | nawk -v VAR=$n '
        {
            split($1,ARR,"|")
            if (VAR == ARR[1]){
                printf ARR[2] " ";
                exit;
            }
        }' 
    done

}
shellfun() {
    for n in $NUMBERS
    do
        for x in $XNUMBERS
        do
            if test "$n" -eq "${x%%\|*}"
                then
                echo "${x##*\|}";
                break;
            fi
            continue;
        done
    done
}
sleep 1
time awkfun;
echo "\nAWK TIME\n\n-----------------------------";
time shellfun;
echo "\nSHELL TIME\n\n-----------------------------";
time numfun;
echo "\nNUMBERS TIME\n\n-----------------------------";
time xnumfun;
echo "\nXNUMBERS TIME\n\n-----------------------------\n\nTOTAL TIME\n";
```

**Results**

Just as a reference, for the results after refining the script, **AWK** average Real time = `0,84` , **SHELL** average Real Time: `0,48`

Comment: Please show a full working script with example input.

Comment: @JohnZwinck refresh and see the script i created, so you can get a better overview of what i am doing, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: As you can conclude from the accepted answer, a tool will help, but your scripting skill will help just as much. Remember: Always try to avoid calling external programs in a long loop.

Comment: And the final time-results are?

Comment: @WalterA just added the results on the post as update, check it out!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your program is slow is not because of printing.  Your program is slow because you invoke a new copy of `nawk` for every element of `$NUMBERS`.  This is very wasteful and you should rethink your program design from the beginning.  It appears you are mostly trying to see which numbers from one list exist in a second list.  If you want to do this in nawk, you should read the entire first list first, and store the elements in an associative array before reading each number from the second file.

You could probably solve this problem more cleanly using `join` or `grep`.

---

Edit: Here's a working solution using `grep`.  It's at least 20x faster than your original `shellfun()`.

```
shellfun2() {
    echo $XNUMBERS | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -d '|' -f1 \
        | grep -f <(echo $NUMBERS | tr ' ' '\n') | rev
}
```

The way it works is to take all the numbers from `$XNUMBERS` before the pipes (so `12|21 34|43` becomes `12\n34`), then pipe those to `grep` with the `-f` argument being all of `$NUMBERS`.  This means we search for all the left-hand sides of `$XNUMBERS` within `$NUMBERS`, and after printing the matches we simply use `rev` to reverse them.  We don't need the right-hand sides of `$XNUMBERS` at all (so maybe you can even stop generating them in the first place, saving more time).

---

Edit: Since you've now told us you are running on Solaris instead of Linux, you don't have `rev`, so you can replace `rev` in the above with this:

```
sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
```

And you can replace `grep` with `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` to get an enhanced version that supports `-f`.

Comment: i dont care of how the variables are created on the first two functions because i am only timing the awkfun and the shellfun, do you have a better idea of how to do the awkfun function entirely in one nawk???

Comment: actually john, arent i doing what you just said? i have everything stored in two variables, and taking them one by one, because i have to check them one by one, in order to print out when the match is true.

Comment: @hedgehog: Can you describe from the beginning, at the top level, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Rather than digging into why running awk so many times is slow, let's talk about what the numbers are actually meaning in your program, and what you're trying to accomplish in plain English.

Comment: Testing if it is faster to do many numbers comparisons between an (n)awk and normal shell scripting... point is the average results at this point is 14,8 seconds for awkfun and 3,7 seconds for shellfun. The difference is too big so i guessed i do something wrong and it needs so much more time. So i am trying to find a way to make awkfun faster.

Comment: so you say that if i would add the for loop and pass to nawk the NUMBERS and XNUMBERS as variables it could be fster..?

Comment: i knew it but i had to check, these things dont work for me because i am running in ksh i already told you, in bash these would totally work, now though: `numlist[2]: rev:  not found
grep: illegal option -- f
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .`

Comment: @hedgehog: You're saying you're on Linux but your `grep` doesn't have a `-f` option?  Which Linux exactly?  As for "rev" you can just install it from your system package manager (not sure what the package name would be, but you can search).

Comment: i never said i run on linux, i said i am running the script on ksh, on unix, sorry if you got mistaken by the linux tag, i just added cause i thought some guy from linux community could be of a help as well, btw i am running unix in an oracle solaris system

Comment: @hedgehog: When you tag your question "Linux" you will get Linux answers.  I will delete the tag now.

Comment: @hedgehog: I have added a section at the bottom of my answer to port the code from Linux to Solaris.  I don't have a machine to test it on, but I suspect it should work.

Comment: Shellfun: When you want to skip substrings, use -x.

Comment: Shellfun: When you want to skip rev, use ` echo $XNUMBERS | tr ' ' '\n'       | grep -f <(echo $NUMBERS | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/.*/^&|/')`

Comment: @WalterA hmmm the sed doesnt seem to work, because it print out the whole XNUMBERS number with the | and the first number in front.... still thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck wow man, you just reduced my `shellfun` time for 700%, ftw man.... you are awesome, thanks a lot...!! plus i managed to reduce the time of the awkfun by 1400% !!!!!!!! i followed what you told me, i put the for loop inside, and i passed the variables and recreated the arrays inside the nawk...!!!! really good info :)

Comment: @hedgehog My remark (only partial solution) is an alternative to find the matching numbers. Of course you can use `|cut -d "|" -f2` for the second part of the string.

Comment: @WalterA anyways thanks a lot, i fixed both awkfun and shellfun, and they are rocking now, 1500% faster time for AWK and 900% faster for SHELL....i dont think that i can make the average_times go less than they are now....

Answer (score 2):

you are launching nawk for every number in $NUMBERS, very expensive in terms of time.

you could filter `$NUMBERS` with grep to only work on the numbers you are interested in. i.e.

```
grep -f FileWithListOfNumbers FileWithListOfXnumbers >matched_numbers
```

will give you a list of XNUMBERS (in matched_numbers) that are also in NUMBERS

Comment: i would totally agree with you, if i didnt have to do it only by using awk :/

Comment: oh, I see you have added more code. in your numfun function, you have the answer: rather than printf assign to an array `NUMBERS[i]=100 + int(rand() * (899))` and in the awk script body iterate over that array (which you show you know how to do already). so the numfun function bit of awk and the awkfun function bit of awk can become one single awk script.

Comment: that array cannot be used by other functions in the script because it is inside the nawk, its local. so i cannot access it through another function