# sed takes more time for processing

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

I have to replace certain characters(around 20 combinations) in each record. I have implemented it using `sed` command. But it takes more than 24 hours if a file is huge (more than 80000 records). Please find the code snippet below:

I have used 2 loops to read input file and read config file where position of each character to be replaced is mentioned. Each line can have more than one character which need to be replaced. When i replace the character i have to convert it to a decimal number as a result position of next replacement character need to be increased.Please find the code snippet below:

```
    ...
    #Read the input file line by line
    while read -r line
    do
 Flag='F'
   pos_count=0

   for pattern in `awk 'NR>1' $CONFIG_FILE`
   do
     field_type=`echo $pattern | cut -d"," -f6`
     if [[ $field_type = 'A' ]];then
        echo "For loop.."
        echo $pattern
        field_type=`echo $pattern | cut -d"," -f6`
        echo field_type $field_type

        start_pos=`echo $pattern | cut -d"," -f3`
        echo start_pos $start_pos
        end_pos=`echo $pattern | cut -d"," -f4`
        echo end_pos $end_pos
        field_len=`echo $pattern | cut -d"," -f5`
if [[ $Flag = 'T' && $field_type = 'A' ]];then
                if [[ $replace = 'R' ]];then
                   pos_count=$(expr $pos_count + 1)
                fi
                echo pos_count $pos_count
                val=$((2 * $pos_count))
                start_pos=$(expr $start_pos + $val)
                end_pos=$(expr $end_pos + $val)
                replace=N

        fi

        echo "$line"
        field=`expr substr "$line" $end_pos 1`
        echo  field $field
        if [[ $start_pos -gt 255 ]];then
                lim=255
                f_cnt=$(expr $start_pos - 1)
                c_cnt=$(expr $end_pos - 2)
                #c_cnt1=$(expr $c_cnt - 255)
                c_cnt1=$(expr $field_len - 2)
                f_cnt1=$(expr $f_cnt - 255)
                echo f_cnt1 "$f_cnt1" , c_cnt1 "$c_cnt1" f_cnt $f_cnt
        else
                lim=$(expr $start_pos - 1)
                f_cnt1=$(expr $field_len - 2)
                echo lim $lim, f_cnt1 $f_cnt1
        fi

        echo Flag $Flag

        case "$field_type" in
           A )
                echo Field type is Amount
                if [[ "${field}"  = "{" ]];then
                        echo "Replacing { in Amount Column"
                    replace=R
                    if [[ $start_pos -gt 255 ]];then
                       line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\(.\{1,$c_cnt1\}\)\([^{]*\){/\1\2+\3.\40/"`
                    else
                       line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\([^{]*\){/\1+\2.\30/"`
fi
                        Flag='T'
                elif [[ "${field}"  = "A" ]];then
                        echo "Replacing A in Amount Column"
                        replace=R
                        if [[ $start_pos -gt 255 ]];then
                                line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\(.\{1,$c_cnt1\}\)\([^A]*\)A/\1\2+\3.\41/"`
                        else
                                line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\([^A]*\)A/\1+\2.\31/"`
                        fi
                        Flag='T'

...
elif [[ "${field}"  = "R" ]];then
                        echo "Replacing R in Amount Column"
                        replace=R
                        if [[ $start_pos -gt 255 ]];then
                                line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\(.\{1,$c_cnt1\}\)\([^R]*\)R/\1\2-\3.\49/"`
                        else
                                line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\([^R]*\)R/\1-\2.\39/"`
                        fi
                        Flag='T'
                else
                        echo "Incremeting the size of Amount Column"
                        replace=R
                        if [[ $start_pos -gt 255 ]];then
                                line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)\(.\{1,$c_cnt1\}\)/\1\2\3  /"`
                        else
                                line=`echo "$line"| sed -e "s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)\(.\{1,$f_cnt1\}\)/\1\2\3  /"`
                        fi
                fi
                ;;
           C )
                echo "Column Type is Count"
                ;;
           * )
                echo Others
                :;
        esac
      fi
   done
   echo "$line" >> ${RES_FILE}
done < "$SRC_FILE"
echo `date`
exit 0
```

Below is the sample input file and config file:

```
CHD0000204H315604COV2013038    PROD2016022016030218481304COVCTR0000204H3156C00000000897         000000229960000024670141D0000000397577I0000000000000{00000174042
55C0000007666170B0000025070425E0000004863873E0000000631900F0000001649128{0000000018756B0000014798809C0000001890129G00000002384500000000286600000000084900000000155300000
0000055000000021388000000000048000000000003            00000897              0000000000000{0000000002706B0000001217827I000000001069
```

Config file:

```
FIELD NO.,FIELD NAME,STARTING POSITION,ENDING POSITION,LENGTH,INDICATOR
1,CHD_CONTRACT_NO,1,5,5,N
2,CHD_FILE_ID,6,21,16,N
3,PHD_CONTRACT_NO,22,26,5,N
4,PHD_PBP_ID,27,29,3,N
5,PHD_FILE_ID,30,45,16,N
6,DET_REC_ID,46,48,3,N
7,DET_SEQ_NO,49,55,7,N
8,DET_DG_CO_ST_CD,56,56,1,N
9,DET_CURR_HICN,57,76,20,N
10,DET_LAST_SUBM_HICN,77,96,20,N
11,DET_LAST_SUBM_CH_ID,97,116,20,N
12,DET_ERL_PDE_ATT_DT,117,124,8,N
13,DET_RX_COUNT,125,135,11,N
14,DET_NET_IGD_COST_AMT,136,149,14,A
15,DET_NET_DISP_FEE,150,163,14,A
16,DET_NET_SAL_TAX_AMT,164,177,14,A
17,DET_NET_GDCB,178,191,14,A
18,DET_NET_GDCA,192,205,14,A
19,DET_NET_GRS_DG_AMT,206,219,14,A
20,DET_NET_PAT_PAY_AMT,220,233,14,A
21,DET_NET_OTR_TROOP_AMT,234,247,14,A
22,DET_NET_LICS_AMT,248,261,14,A
23,DET_NET_TROOP_AMT,262,275,14,A
24,DET_NET_PLRO_AMT,276,289,14,A
25,DET_NET_CPP_AMT,290,303,14,A
26,DET_NET_NPP_AMT,304,317,14,A
27,DET_ORIG_PDE_CNT,318,329,12,N
28,DET_ADJ_PDE_CNT,330,341,12,N
29,DET_DEL_PDE_CNT,342,353,12,N
30,DET_CAT_PDE_CNT,354,365,12,N
31,DET_ATTC_PDE_CNT,366,377,12,N
32,DET_NCAT_PDE_CNT,378,389,12,N
33,DET_NON_STD_CNT,390,401,12,N
34,DET_OON_PDE_CNT,402,413,12,N
35,DET_EST_REB_AT_POS,414,427,14,A
36,DET_VAC_ADM_FEE,428,441,14,A
37,DET_RPT_GAP_DISC,442,455,14,A
38,DET_RPT_GAP_DISC_PDES,456,467,12,N
```

Can anyone suggest any other design approach to reduce the time for processing?

Comment: You don't you use python, php  or perl for this ?

Comment: `sed` uses limited system memory for it's tasks. If you are working with huge files, try to use `perl`

Comment: Every external command you run is another process that needs to spawn. You are spawning **many** commands for each line you read. Using **anything** that will let you stop doing that will **greatly** help speed this up. Additionally the shell is just not at all fast at reading large files. Using **anything** else will therefor also speed this up greatly.  So don't use `expr` if you can use shell arithmetic. Don't use `echo ... | sed` where you can use `sed ... <<<"$stringvar"`, etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Since this is `ksh`, I think `print` should be used in place of `echo`.  I'm not sure `ksh` supports `<<<` (do you know?).

Comment: @JohnZwinck Both `echo` and `print` appear to be built ins in `ksh` though `print` is likely better specified/behaved. The ksh man page on my system lists `<<<` as available but that potential is why I wrote "where you can" since you can't always use it. But you've hit on the other main issue in your answer.

Comment: Just use awk, and the time will be 20 to 30 times smaller.

Comment: I'm amazed that the answers managed to dig as much out of your code as they did.  It is gruesome code (as you know), and you've not clearly specified (at last, AFAIAC) what you're trying to do.  You've not shown the expected output for the sample input.  Is the sample input 3 lines of the 80k lines?  The indentation of your code is erratic which makes it hard to understand too.  I am certain that you should be able to convert the config file once into an appropriate set of processing steps in an appropriate language — which might be Awk, Perl, Python and is almost certainly not shell.

Answer (score 2):

For massively improved performance you'll need to rewrite this.  I suggest Python, Ruby, Awk, Perl, or similar.

The biggest reason why you current have disastrous performance is your nesting of loops is wrong:

```
for line in data:
    for line in config:
        do stuff specified in config to line
```

When you should be doing is:

```
for line in config:
    parse and store line in memory

for line in data:
    do stuff specified in config (in memory)
```

You can do this using any of the above languages, and I promise you those 80,000 records can be processed in just a few seconds, rather than 24 hours.

Comment: and you say this is a serious answer? and it will massively improve the performance???? then what would it be if he would use awk??

Comment: He is already using awk, calling it 80.000 times (for each record). Several external calls reading the config are also done 80.000 times. I am not convinced that avoiding these will make the prog 80.000 times as fast, but it will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

First read the comments and understand that the main problem is the number of calls to external commands called 80.000 times. When this is all done in one program the overhead and performance issues are solved. Which program/tool is up to you.
You will not get close to the the performance when you stick to bash code, but you can learn a lot when you try to use fast internal bash calls where you can.
Some tips when you want to improve your script.

See answer of @John, Only read config file once.

Use `read` for splitting the fields in a line of the config file

```
while IFS="," read -r fieldno fieldname start_pos end_pos length indicator; do  
  ...   
done < configfile
```

Avoid `expr`
Not `f_cnt1=$(expr $field_len - 2)` but `(( f_cnt1 = field_len - 2))`

Redirect to outputfile after the last done, not for each record (currently difficult since you are echoing both debug statements and results).

Delete debug statements

Use <<< for strings

It would be nice when you can change the flow, so that you do not need to call `sed` (80.000 records x 38 config line) times: generate a complex sed script from the config file that can handle all cases and run `sed -f complex.sed "$SRC_FILE"` just once.
When this is to complex, introduce a string `sed_instructions`. For each configfile-line add the sed instruction of that line to the string: `sed_instructions="${sed_instructions};s/\(.\{1,$lim\}\)...."`. Then you only need to call `sed -e ''"${sed_instructions}"'' <<< ${line}` once for each record.
It would be nice when you can generate the string `${sed_instructions}` once before reading the ${SRC_FILE}.

See [which is the fastest way to print in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36881994/3220113) for another example of performance improvements.

I think it can be improved to 10 minutes using bash, 1 minute using awk and less for programs mentioned by @John.